# New SP2013 Farm - Issues with Search and MySites

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search, user-profile-service, my-site

I am stumped, new farm with old topology.

- WFE1 (Web Services / Distributed Cache)
- WFE2 (Web services / Distributed Cache)
- APPS1 (UPS/CA/SEARCH)
- SQL
- WAK1 (no provisioned but for future)

All over SSL through a load balancer. Basic Web Applications (Portal and MySites). Provisioned with AutoSPInstaller.

Everything ran well, initially I had an issue with Search Topology having certain items on the WFE, I reprovisioned search with everything on the APP server.

Issue I am having now is Search is returning error:
Search has encountered a problem that prevents results from being returned.

ULS Logs show quite a few errors but two that strike interest are:

```
User Profile Application Proxy failed to retrieve partitions from User Profile Application: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging :: UserProfileApplicationProxy.ApplicationProperties ProfilePropertyCache does not have c2ca0b79-5666-4057-b087-26f96bd04964    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PartitionIDs()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.IsAvailable    (SPServiceContext serviceContext)
```

This is interesting since I see it when I run into the MySite error (cannot load User Profiles).  The next one is Search Specific.

```
w3wp.exe: All query processing components are in 'Failed' status.
```

Followed by:

```
A failure was reported when trying to invoke a service application: EndpointFailure Process Name: w3wp Process ID: 4344 AppDomain Name: /LM/W3SVC/1444782454/ROOT-1-131413968049090860 AppDomain ID: 2 Service Application Uri: urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:service:ce139799fb784704ab3fed22ca098351#authority=urn:uuid:7f4f14eea35b45de8d8fe8c8ae5273c9&authority=https://sp13-app1:32844/Topology/topology.svc Active Endpoints: 2 Failed Endpoints:1 Affected Endpoint: http://sp13-app1:32843/ce139799fb784704ab3fed22ca098351/SearchService.svc
```

Things I have tried:

Sts3 protocol is sts3s as the whole farm is only available via SSL
Checked permissions on UPS Application --> Farm/MySite/Portal/Services accounts all have full control.  No search account does but I don't think that's required.

Recreated MySites web app and Search with both AutoSPInstaller and SharePoint CA with no luck.

IIS Resets/SP Timer Resets/ Stop&Started UPS/ Same with Search.

Everything else seems to be working just fine. I am ready to pry my eyes out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the above I made a bone head move that hopefully others will avoid.

With our farm setup I had UPS and UPSS running on APP1 but neither on the WFE.  I realized you need to have User Profile Service running on the WFEs as well (not Sync though).  When I started the service on those serves, the EndPoint error was gone and everything worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

From the error you reported, looks like 1st you have to fix the User Profile Service. I would try couple of things

- Stop the UPA sync if you have that
- Stop the UPA service from Central admin > System Settings  > Managed Services on server. Stop UPA service here. repeat this on all the server where it is running.
- Reset the IIS on all the servers. Make Sure no App pool for UPA is listed.
- Now start the UPA services and Sync. test now.

If above not work, i would delete the UPA, make sure no orphan app pool in the IIS related to UPA. recreate UPA from Central admin not via AutoSpinstaller (I never had a luck with it).

For the search service, i am seeing two end point while 1 active and other failed. But you said, you have Search only on one server.  Make sure Search stoped on the server which are not part of it.

I would also clear the Config cache on the server.

Comment: Thanks!  I will follow those instructions.  UPA is up and running on the APP1 server, sync works and no errors but I will still follow your advice since that was my hunch too.  The search topology used to be across all three servers so I am wondering if there is something orphaned there.

Comment: Ok I followed the advice.  I made a mistake in trying to start UPAS on the WFE and it got stuck in starting. So I just went ahead to reprovision UPA.  I tried via PS but it didn't work.  So I tried via Central Admin and it looks good.  It seems no more UPS errors but I still get the Query error above and A failure was reported when trying to invoke a service application: EndpointFailure Process Name: w3wp Process ID: 7816